# Closing active connections using RMySQL

Tags: mysql, r

As per [my question earlier today](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17506021/rmysql-is-finished-uploading-data-mysql-takes-days-for-it-to-appear), I suspect I have an issue with unclosed connections that is blocking data from being injected into my MySQL database. Data is being allowed into tables that are not currently being used (hence I suspect many open connections preventing uploading into that particular table).

I am using RMySQL on Ubuntu servers to upload data onto a MySQL database.

I'm looking for a way to a) determine if connections are open b) close them if they are. The command `exec sp_who` and `exec sp_who2` from the SQL command line returns an SQL code error.

Another note: I am able to connect, complete the uploading process, and end the R process successfully, and there is no data on the server (checked via the SQL command line) when I try only that table.

(By the way,: If all else fails, would simply deleting the table and creating a new one with the same name fix it? It would be quite a pain, but doable.)

Comment: You could try `show full processlist;` to see the open connections.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

a.  `dbListConnections( dbDriver( drv = "MySQL"))`

b.  `dbDisconnect( dbListConnections( dbDriver( drv = "MySQL"))[[index of MySQLConnection you want to close]])`.  To close all: `lapply( dbListConnections( dbDriver( drv = "MySQL")), dbDisconnect)`

Yes, you could just rewrite the table, of course you would lose all data.  Or you can specify `dbWriteTable(, ..., overwrite = TRUE`).

I would also play with the other options, like `row.names`, `header`, `field.types`, `quote`, `sep`, `eol`.  I've had a lot of weird behavior in RMySQL as well.  I can't remember specifics, but it seems like I've had no error message when I had done something wrong, like forget to set row.names.  HTH

Answer (score 15):

Close all active connections:

```
dbDisconnectAll <- function(){
  ile <- length(dbListConnections(MySQL())  )
  lapply( dbListConnections(MySQL()), function(x) dbDisconnect(x) )
  cat(sprintf("%s connection(s) closed.\n", ile))
}
```

executing:
`dbDisconnectAll()`

Comment: This answer is far better than the accepted answer

Answer (score 3):

Simplest:

```
lapply(dbListConnections( dbDriver( drv = "MySQL")), dbDisconnect)
```

List all connections and disconnect them by lapply

Answer (score 2):

**Closing a connection**

You can use dbDisconnect() together with dbListConnections() to disconnect those connections RMySQL is managing:

```
    all_cons <- dbListConnections(MySQL())
    for(con in all_cons) 
      dbDisconnect(con)
```

Check all connections have been closed

```
    dbListConnections(MySQL())
```

You could also kill any connection you're allowed to (not just those managed by RMySQL):

```
    dbGetQuery(mydb, "show processlist")
```

Where mydb is..

```
    mydb = dbConnect(MySQL(), user='user_id', password='password', 
                      dbname='db_name', host='host')
```

Close a particular connection

```
    dbGetQuery(mydb, "kill 2")
    dbGetQuery(mydb, "kill 5")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
lapply(dbListConnections(MySQL()), dbDisconnect)
```

Comment: please explain why do you think this solution works to benefit the community.

Answer (score 1):

In current releases the "dbListConnections" function is deprecated and DBI no longer requires drivers to maintain a list of connections. As such, the above solutions may no longer work. E.g. in RMariaDB the above solutions create errors.

I made with the following alternative that uses the MySQL server's functionality and that should work with current DBI / driver versions:

```
### listing all open connection to a server with open connection
query <- dbSendQuery(mydb, "SHOW processlist;")
processlist <- dbFetch(query)
dbClearResult(query)

### getting the id of your current connection so that you don't close that one
query <- dbSendQuery(mydb, "SELECT CONNECTION_ID();")
current_id <- dbFetch(query)
dbClearResult(query)

### making a list with all other open processes by a particular set of users
# E.g. when you are working on Amazon Web Services you might not want to close 
# the "rdsadmin" connection to the AWS console. Here e.g. I choose only "admin" 
# connections that I opened myself. If you really want to kill all connections,
# just delete the "processlist$User == "admin" &" bit.
queries <- paste0("KILL ",processlist[processlist$User == "admin" & processlist$Id != current_id[1,1],"Id"],";")

### making function to kill connections
kill_connections <- function(x) {
  query <- dbSendQuery(mydb, x)
  dbClearResult(query)
}

### killing other connections
lapply(queries, kill_connections)

### killing current connection
dbDisconnect(mydb)
```